# php validation. Can't quite wrap my head around the logic I need to happen

Tags: php, conditional-statements

I have a page, where there are a 3 values passed and the rest of the page will respond based on any of those 3.
if 1 and 2 have values from a form, but 3 and 4 don't { do a } else warn the user to fill out both 1 and 2

if 1 and 2 don't have values, 3 does, 4 doesn't { do b } else warn the user to fill in 3, disregard the state of 1,2 and 4

if 1 and 2 and 3 don't have values, but 4 does { do c } else warn the user to fill in 4, disregard the state of 1,2, and 3

```
if ($fname != '' and $lname != '') { 
    querytype = "name"; 
} else { 
    echo "Please enter a first and last name."; 
}
if ($reg != '' and $fname == '' and $lname == '') { 
    $querytype = "reg"; 
} else { 
    echo "Please enter a Registration Number."; 
}
if ($num != '' and $reg == '' and $fname == '' and $lname == '') { 
    $querytype = "number"; 
} else { 
    echo "Please enter a Phone Number."; 
}
switch ($querytype) {
    #name is 1 and 2.. it's a first and last name
    case "name": {
        break;
    }
    #reg is 3
    case "reg":
    {
        break;
    }
    #number is 4
    case "number":
    {
        break;
    }
    default: echo "Something broke.. idk";
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with your logic now?

Comment: if I input fields 1 and 2.. I still get the errors for 3 and 4

Comment: Because the `if` condition from the first case is the same as the `else` from 2nd and 3rd case.

Comment: You'd need to skip the following tests if one is done.

Comment: `querytype = "name";` is missing the `$` before `querytype`.

Comment: It would probably be easier if you used nested `if/else` instead of doing them sequentially.

Comment: FYI, you don't need `{}` around the statements in a `case`.

Comment: Your question would be easier to understand if your explanation used the field names instead of numbers. It's not clear which variables are 1, 2, 3, and 4.

Comment: I don't understand this: **if 1 and 2 have values from a form, but 3 and 4 don't { do a } else warn the user to fill out both 1 and 2**. If 1 and 2 have values, why do we tell the user to fill them out?

Comment: I suggest you draw a table that lists all the combinations of the inputs, and what you want to happen in each case.

Comment: Thanks Barmar.. the $ is actually there in the file, just forgot it here.

Comment: Let me renumber to see if it makes more sense
1a = first name
1b = last name
Both of those are required if the user is searching by name
2 = phone number
3 = registration number

So the user has to either choose 1 2 or 3. 
They can:
fill out 1 and leave 2 and 3 blank
or
fill out 2 and leave 1 and 3 blank
or
fill out 3 and leave 1 and 2 blank

Comment: I just figured it out actually.. I didn't need the else statements. Thanks for the responses. :)